# Difference instance of ViewModel for same Composable through Hilt

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I want to have more than one same Composable as a childs of a parent Composable. Each one of them have to request different data to show it to the user.

Is there any way to create different instance of ViewModel to each Composable? By default the ViewModel it's associated to the single activity of the project I think, but I don't know if I could have different ViewModel instances or if I've to share ViewModel and manage the state of each composable inside the ViewModel.

I cannot create different ViewModel because I don't know how many Composables of this type we'll have (I receive all of the dynamically).

Currently I've using Hilt

```
@HiltViewModel
class SampleViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val sampleUseCase: sampleUseCase,
): ViewModel() {
....
}
```

I've been looking for a solution but I haven't found none.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#jetpack-compose "The most important thing to keep in mind when using ViewModel with Compose is that you cannot scope a ViewModel to a composable."

Comment: Are you using [Navigation Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation)? That already scopes ViewModels to each individual screen.